# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined with [group by]

Tags: oracle

in SQL I have these table

```
create table employee(
emp_ssn number(10),
first_name varchar2(10) not null ,
second_name varchar2(10),
last_name varchar2(10) not null ,
address varchar2(20) ,
birthdate date not null  ,
super_ssn number(10),
job_no  number (2),
constraint employee_pk primary key (emp_ssn));
```

---

```
create table job (
job_no number (2),
job_name varchar2(11) ,
constraint job_pk primary key (job_no ));
```

---

and I write a query that display how many employee in each
job using group by

```
SELECT     job_no, job_name,COUNT(emp_ssn)
FROM       job j JOIN employee e
ON         (j.job_no = e.job_no)
GROUP BY   j.job_no, j.job_name;
```

and the output is

```
SELECT     job_no, job_name,COUNT(emp_ssn)
FROM    job j JOIN employee e
ON       (j.job_no = e.job_no)
GROUP BY   j.job_no, j.job_name;
SELECT     job_no, job_name,COUNT(emp_ssn)
```

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

can you help me please !

Comment: Please don't tag every DBMS. Oracle <> sql server <> mysql

Comment: You didn't define WHICH job_no you want in your column list. You should always specify the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT      j.job_no           --<-- you are missing alias here
          , j.job_name         --<-- here
          ,COUNT(e.emp_ssn)    --<-- and here
FROM       job j JOIN employee e
ON         (j.job_no = e.job_no)
GROUP BY   j.job_no, j.job_name;
```